# Is it normal to use <%@include%> with libs like apache tiles?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tiles, apache-tiles

These are my thoughts. Apache tiles is like a manager over jsp files that rules what and where insert. I don't know how it's implemented, maybe something like `<jsp:include>`. Using such approach as this lib offers we have several advantages. It's clear. But does using this lib mean that we have to avoid using static include - `<%@include%>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Static includes using <%@include%> are useful for when that's all you need and offer better performance.

But it does make sense to avoid using <jsp:include ../> when you have the tiles framework in place. In that situation always favour <tiles:insertAttribute ../>

Comment: Thank you for you time. I think this way too. But I decided to ask people's opinion, to be sure.

Comment: By the way - do you know how apache tiles is implemented? Now I'm developing something like it, but I need much more advanced system according to my needs. Maybe we can discuss some principles of design.

Comment: If you want to see a more advanced use case on top of tiles checkout "the ultimate view" tutorial at http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/